# How to show error(s) next to the file upload input fields when PHP throws error(s)

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have a simple HTML form that has three input fields with type="file". The PHP processes uploads in an array. Everything works but I cannot show the error, when occurred, next to the input field in a "div" with class="error_highlight".

I want the two comments on the two "Else" statements close to the bottom of the script to show up when the error occurs. They begin with "Show this error:". Can someone please help me with this?

```
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES['images'])){
    // File upload configuration
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
     
    $images_arr = array();
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val){
        $image_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_name   = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $size       = $_FILES['images']['size'][$key];
        $type       = $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
        $error      = $_FILES['images']['error'][$key];
         
        $fileType = pathinfo($image_name);// split path in its components 
        $extension = strtolower($fileType['extension']);// extract the extension and normalize to lowercase

        if(in_array($extension, $allowTypes)){
            echo $extension;

            if($error === 0){

                    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$extension;
                    $fileDestination = 'user_images/'.$fileNameNew;

                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fileDestination);
                    //header("location: test");

            } else {
                // Show this error as $errors = "An error prevented from uploading your image / file. Please try again.";
            }

        } else {
            // Show this error as $errors = "Unable to upload the selected file type. Please use files or images with extensions ending on jpg / jpeg / png / pdf";

        }
    }
}
```

?>

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file"  name="images[]" >
            <div class="error_highlight"><?php echo $errors; ?></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="file"  name="images[]" >
            <div class="error_highlight"><?php echo $errors; ?></div>
    </div>  

    <div>
        <input type="file"  name="images[]" >
            <div class="error_highlight"><?php echo $errors; ?></div>
    </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
```

Comment: use ajax instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you dont seem to declare $errors but just a looping $error.
You need to Go though errors and use an array to show errors. Like Go though `$_FILES['images']['error']`

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing that, but i could not make it work. I have limited knowledge in dealing with arrays. If you don't mind, could you please show me how?  Alternatively, I could get the value returned through ['image']['error'] to the div'error_hightlight' and use javascript to show different error messages based upon the numerical value returned.